# Url helper with constraints for a subdomain rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-helper

My rails app have two servers and the urls are:

- staging.subdomain.example.com
- subdomain.example.com

And my routes look like:

```
  ['staging.', ''].each do |prefix|
    constraints subdomain: "#{prefix}subdomain" do
      scope module: "subdomain" do
        get "/", to: "pages#home"
        resources :courses, only: [:index, :show]
      end
    end
  end
```

However, when I uses the url helpers, I meet a problem. It always returns the `staging` url.

For example, on production:

```
course_url(132, host: "subdomain.example.com")
=> "http://staging.subdomain.example.com/courses/132"
```

I think the reason is that in the routes, the url helpers are only generated for `staging` constraint, not the other one.

```
$ rate routes
...
courses GET  /courses(.:format)  subdomain/courses#index {:subdomain=>"staging.subdomain"}
        GET  /courses(.:format)  subdomain/courses#index {:subdomain=>"subdomain"}
...
```

Does anyone have a good solution?

Cheers

Comment: have you tried [default_url_options](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/default_url_options)?